# Terraform: How to use key value output

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-kms

I've researched a possible solution for my problem, but it seems mine is more specific.

So, I've a resource `aws_kms_key` which is created by `for_each` expression:

```
for_each = { for keys in var.parameters : keys.name => keys if local.secrets.init.self == true }
```

Nothing specific, everything is working fine, however I don't know how to use an output `arn` of created key. Here is my output:

```
output "key" {
   description = "The 'Amazon Resource Name (ARN)' of 'KMS' key(s)"
   value       = zipmap( 
     values(aws_kms_alias.global)[*].name, values(aws_kms_key.global)[*].arn
   )
}
```

I've used before `for` expression but in that case, I have to use index to allocate the `arn` of kms key, which is obviously not good even not acceptable practice. Here is my old output way:

```
output "key" {
   description = "The 'Amazon Resource Name (ARN)' of 'KMS' key(s)"
   value       = [ for key, value in aws_kms_key.global : value.arn ]
}

Usage

flowlog_encryption  = [{
  keys            = element(module.secrets.*.key, 0)[0]
  retention       = 14
}]
```

The problem with **"old"** way is, when resource is created I can access only with index, and when something is changing, the orders of index is changing too, so when I'm creating a key for `dynamodb` and `flowlogs` the dynamodb took key of `flowlogs` and `flowlogs` tooks key of `dynamodb`, completely random behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new output `key`, the one where `zipmap` is used, is going to produce a map with keys of alias name, and the corresponding values of keys arn. This will be something as follows:

```
output "key" {
   description = "The 'Amazon Resource Name (ARN)' of 'KMS' key(s)"
   value       = {
        alias_name1 = key_arn1
        alias_name2 = key_arn2
        alias_name3 = key_arn3
   }
}
```

Assuming that `module.secrets.key` is your output key above, you would use it as follows:

```
flowlog_encryption  = [{
  keys            = module.secrets.key["alias_name1"]
  retention       = 14
}]
```

or with [lookup](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/lookup.html):

```
flowlog_encryption  = [{
  keys            = lookup(module.secrets.key, "alias_name1", "default_key_arn")
  retention       = 14
}]
```

Comment: Hello, @Marcin, thank you, for your answer, just one question. Is it achievable when I have a more than 5-6 keys? The thing is when the `aliases` is creating it is creates within `kms` key, so it means that in that period I don't know which alias will be there, and how much `keys` will be created, so I think if I will hardcode the `key - value` it wont work

Comment: Yes, it works flawlessly, fantastic, thank you very much @Marcin, as always thank you, and well done